# i/o timeout for read on UDP connection - how to make several attempts to send/read?

Tags: go, error-handling, udp, udpclient

I make a peer to peer application on Go and I can't catch an exception related to the timeout on read from the UDP connection.

I need the program to make maximum *count* attempts to send a message and receive a response, and if nothing works, then exit the loop and continue working.

However, I can't catch the **i/o timeout** exception - the program ends after the first timeout.

How can I fix it?

```
....
bufRes := make([]byte, DATAGRAM_SIZE)

for count > 0 {
        conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(TIMEOUT)) // set Timeout
        count--

        // send message
        buf := composeHandChakeMessage(..some code...)

        _, err := conn.Write(buf)
        if err != nil {
            PanicMessage(err)
            continue
        }

        //recieve answer
        _, _, err = conn.ReadFromUDP(bufRes)
        if err != nil {
            if errors.Is(err, os.ErrDeadlineExceeded) {
                PanicMessage("The respondent is no longer responding\n")                
                continue
            } else {
                PanicMessage(err)               
                continue
            }
        }
        if err == nil {         
            break
        }
    }

....
```

```
2024/01/03 14:57:32 The respondent is no longer responding
goroutine 1 [running]:
log.Panic({0xc0000c5a20?, 0x27?, 0x708080?}) ...
```

the error is :
read udp addr 1 -> addr 2: i/o timeout

Comment: There are no exceptions, and you cannot "catch" them. You are checking for `ErrDeadlineExceeded`, which matches the timeout error, then panicking with the `The respondent is no longer responding` message in your code. I'm not sure what the questions is, what else are you expecting?

Comment: Yes, @JimB, I would like to return to the loop after the panic message to make another attempt to send and receive a message. However, the program terminates, does not continue.

Comment: `panic` terminates the program. If you don't want to panic, then don't call `panic` (or something which calls it for you, like `log.Panic`)

Comment: @JimB thank you very much!! I didn't know it